# HTML generated barcode in outlook message

Tags: html, outlook

I've wrote a VBA code which can generate simple barcodes in HTML format making use of Span elements. Using the same logic as described here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146336/Creating-a-Code-39-Barcode-using-HTML-CSS-and-Java

The barcode works, the popular browsers can render the generated htm file properly, the printed one is properly readable.

Now what i'm trying to do is to embed the barcode in an HTML formatted outlook message generated by VBA macro.

The whole body of the macro created HTML message is rendered fine in Outlook message body, but the bar code does not appear. What can I change in the format of this html in a way that it will appear in outlook as a readable barcode?

I don't need advice on using images or fonts instead. I already know these options. What I need to know is how to make just this method to work with outlook messages.

Actually The barcode code looks like this:

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
  <!- Email body, message, tables, etc...->

  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.06in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.06in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.06in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.06in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.06in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: black 0.06in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>
  <SPAN style="BORDER-LEFT: white 0.02in solid; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1in"></SPAN>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Could it be the lack of content in the spans? Try min-width

Comment: CSS in email programs lacks of support for many things. Consider for example that the proper layout is still rendered using tables instead of divs. i'd think about rendering the barcode the way you want, convert it to an image and embed the image

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the spans a min-width since they are empty and the renderer might collapse them

```html
<span style="border-left: black 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.06in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: black 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: black 0.06in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: black 0.06in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: black 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.06in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: black 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: black 0.06in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: black 0.06in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
<span style="border-left: white 0.02in solid; display: inline-block; height: 1in; min-width: 1px"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the value to equal the `border-left` size in pixels, so it wouldn't mess with the readability of the barcode. Still Outlook can't render it.

Comment: And if you add min-height?